# How to replace href using sed

Tags: sed

How to replace href using sed

`<a href="company.html">COMPANY</a>` to `<a href="company.ejs">COMPANY</a>`

Comment: `sed 's/<a href="\([^.]*\).html">/<a href="\1.ejs">/'` https://sed.js.org/?gist=c2ab2357e63debba8ca3a044f2e42293

Comment: is working thx.